# Jquery: Check if Div is empty and then add css if true

Tags: jquery

This may be quite a simple one.

I have a DIV with the class `.banner-images` which usually contains `img`s. What I would like to do is change the height of its parent div, `#banner-wrapper` if the `.banner-images` is empty.

This is what I have so far:

```
if ('.banner-image:empty') {
    $('#banner-wrapper').css({'height' : '210px'});
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if ($('.banner-image:empty').length) {
    $('#banner-wrapper').css({'height' : '210px'});
};
```

To check if there are no images in the div do this:

```
if ($('.banner-image img').length === 0) {
    $('#banner-wrapper').css({'height' : '210px'});
};
```

Comment: This works only if there is no spaces in the DIV. Is there anyway to make it work only if there are no img's in the div?

Comment: You could use the `height` method.

Comment: I know it's a good habit to use === instead of ==, but I just want to say it's overkill in this case, since we **know** the `.length` property always returns an integer. It's shorter to just test for truthiness.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !$('.banner-image').html().length ) {
    $('#banner-wrapper').css({'height' : '210px'});
};
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.banner-image:empty').size()) {
    $('#banner-wrapper').css({'height' : '210px'});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if no one else is going to post it:

```
if (!$('.banner-image').find('img').length) {  // no images inside .banner-image
    $('#banner-wrapper').css({'height' : '210px'}); 
};
```